# Javascript - How can I differentiate a click and a double click on one element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a click function that triggers when a button is clicked. I am also trying to figure out how to add a double click function onto the same element, that triggers a different event.

```
var click = false;
onEvent("image2", "click", function(event) {
  click = true;
});
if (click === true) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    onEvent("image2", "click", function(event) {
      setScreen("safeScreen");
      console.log("double click");
    });
  }, 200);
} else {
  onEvent("image2", "dblclick", function(event) {
    setScreen("safeScreen");
    console.log("click");
  });
}
```

This code is completely wrong, but I don't know where to start/correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the command that you are looking for is dblclick.

Comment: If the user double clicks, in addition to the double-click handler how many times do you want the single click code to run? Once, twice, or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `click` with `dblclick`
Also check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp)

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/dblclick) or the [*relevant standard*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-dblclick) is preferred. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, I working with javascript only two months) trying to help how i can.
But thanks for advice!)